What is a tight set for a face $F$ of the perfect matching polytope
I was reading the paper The Matching Problem in General Graphs is in Quasi-NC - Ola Svensson, Jakub Tarnawski. There the word mentioned in many places for example Definition 4.1 `$S$ is tight set for the face $F$'.
The perfect matching polytope is defined by the convex hull of the incidence vectors of all perfect matching in a graph. Now for a face $F$ of the polytope $\mathcal{S}(F)=\{S\subseteq V\mid |S|\equiv 1\bmod 2\text{ and }\forall\ x\in F\ x(\delta(S))=1\}$ where $\delta(S)$ denotes the set of all edges incident on $S$ and $x(T)=\sum_{e\in T}x_e$ where $T\subseteq E$. Then what does it mean by $S\in \mathcal{S}(F)$ is tight for the face $F$
